# How can I calculate this integral?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, functions, distributions, inverse

I would like to calculate the integral in equation `pol[x]` if the quantity is positive or negative.

```
a = 2; l = 1; p = 0.5; r = 0.5;

f[x_, a_, l_] := (l^a*x^(a - 1)*Exp[-l*x])/Gamma[a];

F[x_] := Integrate[f[y, a, l], {y, -Infinity, x}];

psi[x_] := InverseFunction[F[x]];

t = Quantile[GammaDistribution[a, 1/l], p];

tailF[y_, a_, l_] := Integrate[f[y, a, l], {y, x, Infinity}];

pol[u_] := 
 Integrate[((1 - u)^r/(1 - p)^(r + 1) + (1 - u)/(1 - p)^2)*(1/
     f[psi[u], a, l]), {u, p, 1}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extended comment.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Since you know that you are dealing with the [`GammaDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GammaDistribution.html), you should make use of the built-in functions rather than doing multiple integrals.

```
dist = GammaDistribution[a, 1/l];
```

To be a valid distribution requires

```
$Assumptions = DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist]

(* a > 0 && 1/l > 0 *)
```

`f` is the [`PDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html)

```
f[x_, a_, l_] = PDF[dist, x] // Simplify[#, x > 0] &

(* (E^(-l x) l^a x^(-1 + a))/Gamma[a] *)
```

`F` is the [`CDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CDF.html)

```
F[x_, a_, l_] = CDF[dist, x] // Simplify[#, x > 0] &

(* GammaRegularized[a, 0, l x] *)
```

`psi` is the [`InverseCDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseCDF.html)

```
psi[q_, a_, l_] = InverseCDF[dist, q] // Simplify[#, 0 < q < 1] &

(* InverseGammaRegularized[a, 0, q]/l *)
```

Your `t` is the same as `psi`

```
Assuming[0 < q < 1, psi[q, a, l] == Quantile[dist, q] // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

`tailF` is the complement of the `CDF`

```
tailF[y_, a_, l_] = 1 - CDF[dist, y] // Simplify[#, y > 0] &

(* 1 - GammaRegularized[a, 0, l y] *)
```

For your specified parameters

```
{f[x, a, l], F[x, a, l], psi[q, a, l]} /.
  {a -> 2, l -> 1, p -> 1/2, r -> 1/2} //
 Simplify[#, x > 0 && 0 < q < 1] &

(* {E^-x x, GammaRegularized[2, 0, x], InverseGammaRegularized[2, 0, q]} *)
```

It is not clear what you are trying to do with `pol`. `u` cannot be an argument to `pol` unless it is restricted to being a Symbol since `u` is used as the variable of integration. Also, it is unusual to see the `PDF` as a divisor. If you are trying to do an expectation, you would multiply by the `PDF` rather than divide. Further, if doing an expectation, you should use the built-in function [`Expectation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expectation.html).